# What English word can be used to describe someone indirectly helping you?

Tags: word-choice, slang

For Example, I want to date a girl but can't seem to get to meet her in order to ask her out. Then suddenly we get invited both to a party of a mutual friend who has no idea I want to date the girl. During the party I ask the girl out and she says yes.

So what happened here is that the mutual friend was sort of a wing-man, but he didn't know he was one, so I wouldn't use that word.

There is a word that is sort of the opposite of this one in slang, "Cockblocker", but not exactly.

Can anyone help me find a word for "Reverse Indirect Cockblocker"? I know this is a ridiculous question but I would appreciate help, Thanks :)

Comment: I think that much of time time this sort of thing is attributed (sometimes facetiously) to a divine entity like a "guardian angel." Which isn't exactly what you're asking after. I don't believe that there is a slang or ordinary phrase for this. At least, nothing that I'm aware of. Coining "Accidental Wing-Man" or "Reverse Indirect Cokblocker" would probably not be inappropriate.

Comment: @sirosen Yea I realized that the slang terms aren't of an appropiate use here. Thanks for your help anyway :)

Comment: Unwitting accomplice might work

Comment: @publicwireless Not sure about that, since that is mostly used in illegal meanings (like unwitting burglary accomplice). But thanks for the answer anyways

Comment: How about "my new best friend"? ;)

Comment: The beauty of the English language is that it's OK to borrow a word or expression from another off-beat source (such as "unwitting accomplice") and the *context* of how the expression is used will usually clear the taint of the original expression and add a richness to the new use of the expression.  For example - maybe the friend that invited you to the party is "guilty" of helping you steal the girl's heart!  God, I love language!

Comment: *Accessory to the crime*.

Comment: A good word for the random event (the party) leading to a positive outcome (she was there and said yes) is **serendipity** ... but that doesn't describe your mutual friend, it describes the role he played.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good word for the random event (the party) leading to a positive outcome (she was there and said yes) is [**serendipity**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serendipity), though that doesn't describe your mutual friend, it describes the role he played.

> [**Full Definition of SERENDIPITY**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/serendipity)
>
> *:  the faculty or phenomenon of finding valuable or agreeable things not sought for; also :  an instance of this*
>
> **Examples of SERENDIPITY**
>
> They found each other by pure *serendipity.*
>
> As they leapfrog from South Africa to Singapore in search of local
>   delicacies, the authors prove again and again that *serendipity* is the
>   traveler's strongest ally: many of their most memorable meals issue
>   from the hands of generous strangers … —Sarah Karnasiewicz, Saveur,
>   June/July 2008

Answer (score 1):

Philosophically casual though English is, we do try to keep some foothold on logic. Since the friend did not knowingly assist in the meeting, no agency can be attributed to him and no noun describes his role.

But you could describe his party as fortuitous or (if you are pious) as providential.

Answer (score 0):

While I do not have a single word to provide you, there is a perfectly viable construct that is in regular use.  You may find it is still too strong of an expression for your situation.

*unwitting matchmaker*

> In my most recent relationship, my friend turned out to be an unwitting matchmaker.