# What is a word or phrase for how you feel when you discover something that you don't think you can have

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

The title is relatively self-explanatory.  For example, I have been introduced to something that I want but only a few people will get one (e.g. winning the lottery, finding a four leaf clover, or getting a certain job).

What word or phrase succinctly describes what you feel in that moment?

**Edit:** to clarify, there may be a chance that you'll get the thing you want, it might require a lot of luck or hard work, etc., but the idea is that you don't know.  Like a mix of serendipity, despair, and determination.

Comment: On the basis that "benefit by happenstance, by birth, unsought-for" and "someone indirectly helping you" are much the same thing, maybe this is a duplicate of [*What English word can be used to describe someone indirectly helping you?*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/238003/) (where the accepted answer is ***serendipity***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I think the OP is asking for the feeling when you know you can't get it, rather that when you actually do get it.

Comment: @A.Ellett: Why isn't anyone reading the question? How can you be elated on finding out you may never get what you dearly want?

Comment: @Tushar: oic. You're quite right. I read *discover* and *have been introduced to* as NNS for *find, get, experience*. The request for a name of the *reaction* strikes me as completely a matter of opinion, depending on what particular feelings any given speaker might have (always allowing for the fact that emotional states are at best loosely labeled). I might be ***wistful***, for example. But that's just me.

Comment: @A.Ellett it's too strong in one direction, it only describes the happiness.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I like your suggestion of ***wistful***

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Wistful seems to fit. But I've only seen it used for things in the past.

Comment: randomusername, so you're a "defeatist" too? You should maybe look to see if anyone else is ***inspired***. That's to say grateful for the *serendipity* that showed you this potential prize, and *determined* to fulfill your destiny and actually *get* it. (Even if the only effort you're actually going to make is to buy a lottery ticket! :)

Comment: The feeling of one such experience was caught in the book title The_Unbearable_Lightness_of_Being  for which there is an explanatory Wiki

Comment: @Hugh: That might end up focusing on how "trivial" the prize is, in the grand scheme of things (*being* being such a fragile, ephemeral, and meaningless state). In which case instead of such a long name/title, the reaction might best be summed up as [***Meh***](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Meh)

Comment: It depends on the "prize" and how much you actually "need" this. If the prize for a lottery  is a new car, and the competition is held at your local supermarket, you might feel you have a chance of winning, compared to a national lottery where the jackpot is a huge sum of money, but millions of tickets are sold every week. Do I care about finding a four-leaf clover? Why should I? Do I care about finding a job? Yes, very much so. But my finding a job is dependent on many different factors, one of which is luck. Whereas  winning a lottery is just pure luck.

Comment: You're looking at *frustration* [**In people, internal frustration may arise from challenges in fulfilling personal goals and desires, instinctual drives and needs,**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frustration)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, denotationally speaking that is probably the closest word there is.  But the connotation is all wrong.

Comment: what about something like "poor"  :/  saddest word in English!

Comment: what about it makes you feel "pathetic" or in slang "like a loser" ?

Answer (score 3):

You realize it is ***out of reach*** and you feel ***disenchanted***.

> [Out of reach or beyond reach](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/in%20reach)
>
> meaning “unattainable”; for example, This plan is out of reach for most subscribers, or His explanation is beyond my reach.
>
> [disenchant](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/disenchant)
>
> to rid of or free from enchantment, illusion, credulity, etc.; disillusion:
>   The harshness of everyday reality disenchanted him of his idealistic hopes.

Comment: The OP is asking for phrases that describe the feeling when you realize something is unattainable, not synonyms for the unattainable object itself.

Comment: added disenchanted

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that we all get the same feeling when that happens.

For some, it could be disappointing, or even **[humbling](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/humble?q=humbling#humble__11)**

> Cause (someone) to feel less important or proud:
>
> When I finally accepted that my childhood dream of becoming a soccer player would never be realized, it was a humbling experience for me.

But then again, some might react like Tyler Durden did:

> We've all been raised on television to believe that one day we'd all be millionaires, and movie gods, and rock stars. But we won't. And we're slowly learning that fact. **And we're very, very pissed off.**

EDIT: After reading your edit, I have to admit I can't quite name that particular feelings cocktail. Yet.